# Solidify modifier glitch/detachment

Tags: solidify-modifier

Very weird solidify glitch: when I apply it, it just peels off from my model. Screenshots are here. Idk how to add .blend here :c

[image: Solidify properties on screen are correct, im using them on other models and theres no issue]

[image]

[image]